# FFmpeg (Thumbnail from video) works in command line, but not in PHP script

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

**I looked at the similar questions, and the solutions there do not work in my case. Anyone has any idea? I am trying to capture a thumbnail from a given video file.**

Later, my goal is to capture a thumbnail from live streaming video file.

**Below is my current set up.**

Linux Ubuntu    16.04

PHP version 7.0

Nginx Version   1.10.3

FFmpeg Version  FFmpeg 2.8.11

**I installed FFmpeg through below commands in my Ubuntu server.**

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

**When I type the below command line in the terminal, it does the conversion fine.**

```
ffmpeg -i /etc/nginx/html/test.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -vf scale=240:120 /etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/test.png;
```

In order to use it in php file, I confirmed the location of ffmpeg binaries by I typing in the terminal, `which ffmpeg`, and it returns `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`

I also gave permission to the directory by using `chmod 755` command line.

**Here is what I have in my ffmpeg.php file.
I included the full path to my ffmpeg as you can see.**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

$ffmpeg = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
$videoFile="/etc/nginx/html/test.mp4";
$thumbnail= "/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg";

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -vf scale=240:120 $thumbnail 2>&1 &";

$output = shell_exec($cmd);
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
?>
```

**This returns the message like below.**

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/etc/nginx/html/Share/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1321 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:23], 932 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[swscaler @ 0x1621be0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 240x120 [SAR 20:23 DAR 40:23], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x16165a0] Could not open file : /etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=3.9 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A    
video:8kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

**UPDATED: I also gave permission to ffmpeg by chmod +x $(which ffmpeg)**

I tried `php /etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.php` in the terminal, and it also does conversion fine.

```
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/etc/nginx/html/Share/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1321 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:23], 932 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[swscaler @ 0x72dbe0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 240x120 [SAR 20:23 DAR 40:23], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=3.9 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A    
video:8kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have permission to access `/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg` ?

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Yes, I gave permission to access that path. I installed FFmpeg through apt-get install ffmpeg, and that's it. Using shell_exec() requires ffmpeg-php installation?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. In my server, I am also using ffmpeg by shell_exec, no issue whatsoever. Though you have mentioned giving permission to the folder, I still think there's some kind of permission problem. Can you try to create test file to that path using `file_get_contents` ? Let's see if it returns any error.

Comment: @Ataur Rahman I just created test.txt ("Hello There!") in the ~/thumbnails directory. And, in my test.php file I wrote `$dir = file_get_contents('/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/test.txt'); echo "test->".$dir;` This returns no error, test->Hello There!, so I guess the permission is fine. It is really werid...

Comment: I also tested if shell_exec() is executing properly or not. `$cmd = shell_exec('ls'); echo "cmd->".$cmd;` and it returns fine.

Comment: oh my bad, can you try `file_put_contents` to create file, I mentioned the wrong function earlier !

Comment: @AtaurRahman Oh okay, file_put_contents is not working. Even though I gave chmod -R 777 to the path, it is not writable. weird... `Warning: file_put_contents(/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/test.txt): failed to open stream:`

Comment: @AtaurRahman I executed the following command `chown www-data:www-data '/etc/nginx/html/'` (shorter path), and `touch /etc/nginx/html/thumbnail.jpg` works fine. I was happy to see the result. However, this path `/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/` is not working. Do you think this may cause permission problem? `Share folder` is the symbolic link I made from `/media/Share/` that is sharing folder with my host OS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don‘t have the right permissions for the directory
`/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/`

That, at least, is what I get from the error message `Could not open file : /etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg`.

A quick and dirty way to test, if this is the reason for the problem, would be to change the directories permissions level to 777. (of course revert this afterwards)

Comment: I just gave chmod 777 /etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/, and it still does not work.

Comment: @JunKim Do you get the same error message? Is it possible that the file "thumbnail1.jpg" already exists from a former test with your user account and the web-user does not have the permissions to modify the file? (you could try to execute chmod -R 777 on the directory)

Comment: Yes, still having the same error message. I deleted all the tested image files and tried it again. Still the same... What problem it might be...? As far as i can tell, shell_exec() is executing properly as i tested with the basic linux command, ffmpeg is installed correctly, and permission to the path is already granted by using chmod 777. Well,,, hope i can solve it out within hours.

Comment: @JunKim The next steps I would take, would be: 1. Modify the php scrip to just create an empty file in `/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg`, so, something like: `$cmd = "touch $thumbnail";` and check if the file is created successfully (this should rule out any permission issue). 2. Execute the php script as the webserver user from the command line and check the results.

Comment: I thought about it for a while. Is there anything that I should have done to link php7.0 with ffmpeg?

Comment: @JunKim Anyone correct me, if I‘m wrong, but I don‘t hink so, otherwise the script would fail completely (ffmpeg can‘t be executed). Also this hasn‘t much to do with PHP, because with the shell_execute function you delegate the to be executed command to the system.

Comment: I just put this code `$thumbnail = "/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/thumbnail1.jpg";
$cmd = "touch $thumbnail";
echo shell_exec($cmd);` in php file. When i executed it, it does not create any file in that directory...(From the terminal, the file is created successfully) So it should be permission issue i guess?

Comment: @JunKim Yep, exactly, so that must be a permission issue. Please execute the following command and then try your script again: `chmod -R 777 /etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/` . I‘m really curios about the result!

Comment: I took a rest for a while and just came back. I gave chmod -R 777 permission to that path, and it still does not work. I am really curious why... it is not writtable. I tested with shorter path `touch /etc/nginx/html/thumbnail.jpg`, and it is working as well.

Comment: I executed the following command `chown www-data:www-data '/etc/nginx/html/'` (shorter path), and `touch /etc/nginx/html/thumbnail.jpg` works fine. I was happy to see the result. However, this path `/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/` is not working. Do you think this may cause permission problem? `Share folder` is the symbolic link I made from `/media/Share/` that is sharing folder with my host OS.

Comment: Without the `-R` parameter the `chown` command only changes the permissions for the folder it is executed on, but not on the subdirectories. Which means, that your `/etc/nginxs/html/` now should be owned by www-data, but it seems that this ist not the case for `/etc/nginx/html/Share/ffmpeg/thumbnails/`. Regarding the symbolic link: I‘m not sure, but it might be possible that this makes the case a little bit more complicated. What I would do, would be to execute `chown -R www-data:www-data '/etc/nginx/html/'`, so that this is applied to all subfolders and check if this solves the issue already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. StackOverFlow is such a great site! I organized the solution below regarding the permission issue and the symbolic link. I had to give access write/read to the sharing folder in host operating system.

Answer (score -1):

I SOLVED the above issue with great help from @Tek and @AtaurRahman.

**It was permission issue**

I had to execute the chown / chmod commands to the path

```
chmod -R 777 'path';
chown -R www-data:www-data 'path';
```

**chown command**: changes the user and/or group ownership of for given file

**chmod command**: changes file access permissions (read and write access).

I also had the permission problem for sharing folder with my host operating system.

As you can see my question above, **/etc/nginx/html/Share/~** is where

I wanted to write a .jpg file. I gave access **read/wrtie to everyone** to the sharing folder in my host OS, it works perfectly. (I am not sure if this causes any security issue later on. If anyone knows about this, feel free to comment below to share)

**I hope this helps someone who is facing the same problem**